# Android Tumblr login issue “JumblrException android

Tags: android, authentication, tumblr, jumblr

**What I have**

I have a photo where I need to post it to `Tumblr`

**What I did**

I authorised the user and got **token,secretToken**

**My problem**

The **token,secretToken** that I received is different from the [Tumber Explore API](https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info) , so I get **com.tumblr.jumblr.exceptions.JumblrException: Unauthorized**

**My code**

```
private void tumblrLogin() {
        preferencesTumblr = PostPhotoActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("tumblr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PostPhotoActivity.this, "Logging in", "Please Wait...");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(TUMBLR_CONSUMER_KEY, TUMBLR_SECRET_KEY);
                    provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(REQUEST_URL, ACCESS_URL, AUTHORIZE_URL);
                    String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, TootleTumblr.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
                    PostPhotoActivity.this.startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(authUrl)), TootleTumblr.WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE_TUMBLR);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

OnActivityResult

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencesTumblr.edit();
            editor.putString("requestToken", consumer.getToken());
            editor.putString("requestSecret", consumer.getTokenSecret());
            editor.commit();
            makeTumblrOn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble. Use a library to get through to Tumblr.. 
It will return the Token and Secret Token. Use it in with Jumblr so you can access it's APIs. No more `unauthorized` exceptions.

Github Link : [Loglr](https://github.com/dakshsrivastava/Loglr)